# Not able to get response body using GatewayFilter

Tags: filter, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring api gatway filter. Here I need to get the response from the microservice and then I need to cache the response in the form of string in redis server. Below is the complete code.

```
@Component
public class CacheFilterGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CacheFilterGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {

private final ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String> reactiveRedisOperations;

public CacheFilterGatewayFilterFactory(ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String> reactiveRedisOperations) {
    super(Config.class);
    this.reactiveRedisOperations = reactiveRedisOperations;
}

@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        String cacheKey = exchange.getRequest().getURI().toString();
        return getFromCache(cacheKey).flatMap(cachedResponse -> {
            if (cachedResponse != null) { // Cache hit - serve the cached response
                exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return exchange.getResponse()
                        .writeWith(Mono.just(exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(cachedResponse.getBytes())));
            } else { 
                return callActualService(chain, exchange);
            }
        }).switchIfEmpty(callActualService(chain, exchange));
    };
}

private Mono<? extends Void> callActualService(GatewayFilterChain chain, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    ServerHttpResponse originalResponse = exchange.getResponse();

    ServerHttpResponseDecorator responseDecorator = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(originalResponse) {
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> writeWith(final Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
            return Flux.from(body)
                    .doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                        dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                        DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                        String responseBody = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        // Log the response body
                        System.out.println("Response Body: " + responseBody);

                    })
                    .then(super.writeWith(body));
        }
    };

    // Continue with the filter chain using the decorated response
    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().response(responseDecorator).build());
}

private Mono<String> getFromCache(String key) {
    return reactiveRedisOperations.opsForValue().get(key);
}

private void putInCache(String key, String value) {
    reactiveRedisOperations.opsForValue().set(key, value).subscribe();
}

public static class Config {
    // Add any configuration properties needed for your custom filter
}
```

}

Problem:
I am able to call the actual service, but I am not able to get the body from the response what I got.
The problem is writeWith method is not getting executed. Do I missing something in reactive way of programming?

Why the writeWith method is not executed?